# How to extract data from a list of dictionaries from a filter

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries which is a **scrape** of HTML elements from a forum:

```
[{'title': 'aaa', 'responses': '1 response', 'url': 'https://www.example.com/aaa'}, {'title': 'bbb', 'responses': '4 responses', 'url': 'https://www.example.com/bbb'}, {'title': 'ccc', 'responses': '2 responses', 'url': 'https://www.example.com/ccc'}, {'title': 'ddd', 'responses': '8 responses', 'url': 'https://www.example.com/ccc'}, {'title': 'eee', 'responses': '2 responses', 'url': 'https://www.example.com/eee'}]
```

I want to extract the 'url' items from the dictionaries if the 'reponses' item is smaller than 2 responses.
I try this code which works well but only for the first item:

```
dict = {'url1': ''}
item1 = "1 response"
item2 = "2 responses"
if item1 in scrape[0]['responses'] or item2 in scrape[0]['responses']:
    dict['url1'] = scrape[0]['url']
    print(dict)

{'url1': 'https://www.example.com/aaa'}
```

If I delete the [0] element I get this: *TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str*

I want this result:

```
{'url1': 'https://www.example.com/aaa', 'url2': 'https://www.example.com/eee'}
```

How to do this?

Comment: Do you want to include 2 responses? if so, why the expect result does not have `https://www.example.com/eee`? Besides, do you want your result `dict`'s key to be enumerated?

Comment: Just to clarify: Your question is how to do this *for each_entry in the_scrap*, correct?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I made a mistake in the attended result. I edit my post. And yes, I want to test each entry in the scrap to search for the 'responses' element and extract data depending on the number: if it's <= 2, I extract the 'url' data to my second dictionary.

Comment: Do you know what a ``for`` loop is?

Comment: Yes, but since I'm a beginner with Python this kind of action is a little bit too advanced for my skills level. This a good exercise to start to learn, anyway. Thanks to the other members which posted here, I'm upgrading very fast ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function and use `filter(...)` on the list:

```
lst = [{'title': 'aaa', 'responses': '1 response', 'url': 'https://www.example.com/aaa'}, {'title': 'bbb', 'responses': '4 responses', 'url': 'https://www.example.com/bbb'}, {'title': 'ccc', 'responses': '2 responses', 'url': 'https://www.example.com/ccc'}, {'title': 'ddd', 'responses': '8 responses', 'url': 'https://www.example.com/ccc'}, {'title': 'eee', 'responses': '2 responses', 'url': 'https://www.example.com/eee'}]

def few_responses(item):
    number, _ = item['responses'].split()
    if (int(number) < 2):
        return True
    else:
        return False


for item in filter(few_responses, lst):
    print(item["url"])
```

Alternatively you can use a list comprehension that does the same:

```
urls = [item["url"]
        for item in lst
        for number, _ in [item["responses"].split()]
        if (int(number) < 2)]
print(urls)
```

Comment: Many thanks. I updated your code to change this: `if (int(number) <= 2)]` and I get what I wanted

Comment: I have put an upvoting and accepted it. You will not see the upvote as I do not have enough reputation at this time but it is well registered. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the list, and convert each value of the "responses" key into an int, then check if it is smaller than 2 and if so, print the URL (inserted an extra item, `fff`in `l` for clarity):

```
l = [{'title': 'aaa',
      'responses': '1 response',
      'url': 'https://www.example.com/aaa'
      },
     {'title': 'bbb', 'responses': '4 responses', 'url': 'https://www.example.com/bbb'},
     {'title': 'ccc', 'responses': '2 responses', 'url': 'https://www.example.com/ccc'},
     {'title': 'ddd', 'responses': '8 responses', 'url': 'https://www.example.com/ccc'},
     {'title': 'eee', 'responses': '2 responses', 'url': 'https://www.example.com/eee'},
     {'title': 'fff', 'responses': '1 responses', 'url': 'https://www.example.com/fff'}
 ]


def less_responses_than_n(r, n=2, count=0):
    for d in l:
        if int(d["responses"].split()[0]) < n:
            count += 1
            r[f'url_{count}'] = d["url"]
    return r


r = dict()
print(less_responses_than_n(r))
print(less_responses_than_n(r, n=3))
```

Returning:

```
{'url_1': 'https://www.example.com/aaa', 'url_2': 'https://www.example.com/fff'}
{'url_1': 'https://www.example.com/aaa', 'url_2': 'https://www.example.com/ccc', 'url_3': 'https://www.example.com/eee', 'url_4': 'https://www.example.com/fff'}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the type of results I'm searching for.

Comment: I am very happy to hear it

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using a simple iteration  and `str.split`

**Ex:**

```
data = [{'title': 'aaa', 'responses': '1 response', 'url': 'https://www.example.com/aaa'}, {'title': 'bbb', 'responses': '4 responses', 'url': 'https://www.example.com/bbb'}, {'title': 'ccc', 'responses': '2 responses', 'url': 'https://www.example.com/ccc'}, {'title': 'ddd', 'responses': '8 responses', 'url': 'https://www.example.com/ccc'}, {'title': 'eee', 'responses': '2 responses', 'url': 'https://www.example.com/eee'}]
res = [item['url'] for item in data if int(item['responses'].split()[0]) < 2]
print(res)  # --> ['https://www.example.com/aaa']
```